# Error al ejecutar el comando npm start en React js

Tags: reactjs, npm

quisiera que me ayudaran a resolver este error que me tira cuando ejecuto el comando npm start, no se si tengo que instalar otra cosa pero todos desde que le doy npx create-react-app va bien pero cuando ejecuto el comando npm start me tira error, el que me diga como solucionarlo muchas gracias.

[image: imagen que muestra el error que me tira]

---

aqui esta la imagen del package.json, estube revisando y esta completo asique no se porque me sigue tirando ese error al ejecutar el npm start

[image: imagen del package json]

Comment: Que versión de node estás utilizando? Ademas, fijate que no haya una carpeta `node_modules` o un `package.json` dando vueltas en: `C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto :

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Comment: gracias, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, no se si se podria solucinar de otra forma o si tengo que borrar alguna archivo

Comment: Puedes mostrar una imagen del package.json?

Comment: la pondre como comentario para que la veas.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo error, vi muchas opciones pero la clásica fue reiniciar la máquina y todo volvió a la normalidad, pero antes de reiniciarla tomé y usé

```
npm install
```

Luego de un reinicio todo funcionó. Si no te es suficiente, borra los módulos y vuelve a tipear

```
npm install
```